# seperate a group of same values in a column to different columns in excel

Tags: excel

What formula do I use to transfer to different columns same values in a column?
I also want to pair it with the value on the next column.

```
Column A    Column B
CAR           10
CAR            5
BUS           20
Bus           30
```

Result should be

```
Column A     Column B    column C    column D
CAR            10          Bus          20
CAR             5          Bus          30
```

Comment: Can you be more specificwhat you want to do and say what you have tried? You have Sheet 1 with A B and want to copy the rows alternatively to Sheet2 A B and Sheet2 C D?

Comment: hi Roland, hope the edited version makes sense.

Comment: Have you considered using VBA for this task? or dows it have to be a formula?

Comment: Hi Roland, kind of new at this, what ever works I guess, it can be VBA or a formula.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the prettiest but you can do these equation in each cell you want a result. This will look in the A column and return the value `CAR` for a match. Just estimate how many values will return. For example copy and paste this equation in column A of sheet2 in rows 1-10. If there is not a match it will return blank.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$4, SMALL(IF("CAR"=$A$1:$A$4, ROW($A$1:$A$4)-MIN(ROW($A$1:$A$4))+1, ""), ROW($A1))), "")
```

Change the array after `INDEX` to change what gets returned. Put this equation in column B row 1-10 to return the equivalent number value.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$4, SMALL(IF("CAR"=$A$1:$A$4, ROW($A$1:$A$4)-MIN(ROW($A$1:$A$4))+1, ""), ROW($A1))), "")
```

These equations need to be entered as array formulas with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`

Then change the equation for each value to check for.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$4, SMALL(IF("BUS"=$A$1:$A$4, ROW($A$1:$A$4)-MIN(ROW($A$1:$A$4))+1, ""), ROW($A1))), "")

 =IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$4, SMALL(IF("BUS"=$A$1:$A$4, ROW($A$1:$A$4)-MIN(ROW($A$1:$A$4))+1, ""), ROW($A1))), "")
```

Updated:
It would be easier to accomplish this through VBA but one way I can think of is to use

```
AA2=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$4, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($AA$1:AA1, $A$2:$A$4), 0)), "")
```

to create a new list of all unique values. This equation has to be put in Row 2 not row 1 and be entered with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`. Copy this equation in more rows than you have unique values. Then change the value looked for to this new column. So change `"CAR"` to `...IF($AA$2=$A1:$A$4` and change `"BUS"` to `...IF($AA$3=$A1:$A$4...`

Comment: hi bbishopca, can the formula look for any unique value in column A and put it in the results sheet column A, then column C, then column E etc?

Comment: I added an edit to add a solution to this. Try it out.